# Qi Charger broken magnetic backing plate

Tags: charger, coil, wireless-charging

My Qi charger module arrived with a broken backplate. It appears to be some sort of magnet.

1. What is the exact purpose of this backplate? Is it meant to amplify the signals or only have them go one way?
2. Will the module work just as well with this broken plate or will it perform worse (longer charge times, more precise placement needed)?

[image: Charging coil from which the magnetic backplate is cracked and pieces are chipped of]

Comment: Try it out and see or, send it back asking for a replacement.

Comment: @Andyaka It works in this configuration, but I would like to know/learn the use of this magnetic part. Since I want to build a custom Qi charger. Also, since I only have one module, I can not compare its performance with another one.

Comment: You said it appears to be a magnet. Is it attractive to iron?

Comment: It does not, I don't know why I didn't test that.. :') See @Arsenal's answer for what it actually is.

Comment: I know what it is if it isn't a magnet but you said it was a magnet!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These plates are ferrite sheets. They are used to conduct the magnetic field, to increase the efficiency of the energy transfer. As it conducts the magnetic field, it will also reduce the magnetic field behind the ferrite sheet, which is quite important on the receiver side (less electromagnetic interference, less eddy current losses, less heat).

A broken sheet will decrease the positive effect of the ferrite sheet. This means the charger will lose efficiency. This could potentially lead to overheating of the charger. Depending on the implementation it will catch fire or turn down the power level to prevent overheating, resulting in a longer charge time.

I'd get it replaced if you want to use it for a prolonged time, if you use it without having it in sight, I'd definitely get it replaced.